# How to disable super+space key in Unity?

Tags: unity

After a recent update (or maybe I missed that somehow) Unity does not allow to use <kbd>super+space</kbd> key now.
Instead it shows a language swithing box in the middle of the screen.

[image]

I couldn't find this in keyboard settings, shortcuts.
Any way to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another update this problem disappeared. (At least I can't tell what else I did)